# Scrapy script running without exception,but no data collected

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Here is a Python Scrapy script which I am learning from some material book. 
It is a simple web scraping sample.
I can run it without any exception.But it seems no data actually collected by running it. 
So I past the code bellow, could anyone be kind to try running it and let me know if it works for you? cuz this is learning sample I don't think it is wrong, or maybe my python lib not match. thank you.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class PythonEventsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pythoneventsspider'

    start_urls = ['https://www.python.org/events/pythonevents/',]
    found_events = []

    def parse(self, response):
        for event in response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "list-recent-events")]/li'):
            event_details = dict()
            event_details['name'] = event.xpath('h3[@class="event-title"]/a/text()').extract_first()
            event_details['location'] = event.xpath('p/span[@class="event-location"]/text()').extract_first()
            event_details['time'] = event.xpath('p/time/text()').extract_first()
            self.found_events.append(event_details)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({ 'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR'})
    process.crawl(PythonEventsSpider)
    spider = next(iter(process.crawlers)).spider
    process.start()

    for event in spider.found_events: print(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy spider callback methods can return (or yield) two things:

1. [Requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)
2. [Items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html)

On the code you shared there is a first request (against the sites defined in `start_urls`) and the `parse` method is the default callback method for all requests (if no `callback` argument is specified).

That `parse` method should return an Item or a Request, and you are not doing that, so you should change it something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for event in response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "list-recent-events")]/li'):
        event_details = dict()
        event_details['name'] = event.xpath('h3[@class="event-title"]/a/text()').extract_first()
        event_details['location'] = event.xpath('p/span[@class="event-location"]/text()').extract_first()
        event_details['time'] = event.xpath('p/time/text()').extract_first()
        self.found_events.append(event_details)

        yield event_details
```

Now your spider is outputting an item (a `dict` in this case called `event_details`).